# Javascript Cookie is blank if expiration date is set

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm developing a site, and I have an array of ingredients that i convert into a string and then create a javascript cookie so i can later on push this over to a database. Anyways, when I set the cookie as:

```
var list = foods.toString();
document.cookie = "ingredients=" + list + ";";
var x = document.cookie;
alert(x);
```

everything works correctly.

Although if i do:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (0*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
var list = foods.toString();
document.cookie = "ingredients=" + list + ";" + expires;
var x = document.cookie;
alert(x);
```

Then i get a blank cookie

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? And if you have, how do you fix it? I greatly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: When setting expires, you have `(0*24*60*60*1000)`. Note that anything times zero is zero, so you are setting the expiry for now. Remove the leading zero (or use `d.getTime() + 8.64e7`.

Comment: Oh okay, thats right, I meant to have a 10 there just for testing, but since it has 0, it was expiring as soon as it was created. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's working here

```js
var d = new Date(),
  foods = 'food';

d.setTime(d.getTime() + (0 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

var list = foods.toString();

document.cookie = "ingredients=" + list + ";";

document.cookie = expires;

var x = document.cookie;

alert(x);
```